# How-to and Understanding of drag and zoom event with GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, touch, glsurfaceview

I had everything working with this test app I made that displays a 3D object using the standard vertex, color, and point buffer.

I can..

- rotate the object with touch events
- render object with openGL ES 1.0 using GL10
- everything works great

Now I want to be able to zoom in and out using two fingers for a "pinch" motion. I found some good tutorials and sample code, but it is mostly for ImageViews. I am still semi-new to Android and I do not fully understand how to make this zoom function work for GLSurfaceView.

Below is the code I have so far for the Activity class. The first touch handler is for the zoom event I found through a Tutorial designed for ImageView(I used this because I thought it would be an easy conversion). The second handler is for the rotation event, which works just fine.

Thank you ahead of time and I hope this post will help others with the same issue.
I will be standing by for any edits or additions needed.

```
 // Activity for rendering 3D object openGL ES 1.0
 public class GL_ExampleActivity extends Activity
 {
      private GLSurfaceView surface;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           surface = new GL_ExampleSurfaceView(this);
           setContentView(surface);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause()
      {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onPause();
           surface.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume()
      {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onResume();
           surface.onResume();
      }
 }

 class GL_ExampleSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView
 {
      private static final String TAG = "Touch";

      Matrix matrix_new = new Matrix();
      Matrix last_matrix = new Matrix();

      static final int NONE = 0;
      static final int DRAG = 1;
      static final int ZOOM = 2;
      int mode = NONE;

      PointF start = new PointF();
      PointF mid = new PointF();
      float oldDist = 1f;


      private final float SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
      private GLRenderer renderer;
      private float previous_x;
      private float previous_y;

      public GL_ExampleSurfaceView(Context context)
      {
           super(context);

           renderer = new GLRenderer();
           setRenderer(renderer);

           setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
      {
           // handler for drag and zoom events
           switch (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
           {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     last_matrix.set(matrix_new);
                     start.set(e.getX(), e.getY());
                     Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                     mode = DRAG;
                     //requestRender();
                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                     oldDist = finger_distance(e);
                     Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                     if (oldDist > 10f)
                     {
                         last_matrix.set(matrix_new);
                         finger_distance_midpoint(mid, e);
                         mode = ZOOM;
                         Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                     }
                     //requestRender();
                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                     mode = NONE;
                     Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                     //requestRender();
                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                     if (mode == DRAG)
                     {
                          matrix_new.set(last_matrix);
                          matrix_new.postTranslate(e.getX() - start.x, e.getY() - start.y);
                     }
                     else if (mode == ZOOM)
                     {
                          float newDist = finger_distance(e);
                          Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                          if (newDist > 10f)
                          {
                               matrix_new.set(last_matrix);
                               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                               matrix_new.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                          }
                     }
                    //requestRender();
                    break;
            }
           //view.setImageMatrix(matrix_new);



           // handler for rotation event, y and x axis
           float x = e.getX();
           float y = e.getY();

           switch (e.getAction())
           {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float dx = x - previous_x;
                float dy = y - previous_y;

                if (y > getHeight() / 2)
                {
                     dx = dx * -1 ;
                }

                if (x < getWidth() / 2)
                {
                     dy = dy * -1 ;
                }
                renderer.angle_x += dx * SCALE_FACTOR;
                renderer.angle_y += dy * SCALE_FACTOR;
                requestRender();
           }
           previous_x = x;
           previous_y = y;
           return true;
      }


      private float finger_distance(MotionEvent e)
      {
           float x = e.getX(0) - e.getX(1);
           float y = e.getY(0) - e.getY(1);
           return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
      }

      private void finger_distance_midpoint(PointF point, MotionEvent e)
      {
           float x = e.getX(0) + e.getX(1);
           float y = e.getY(0) + e.getY(1);
           point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
      }

 }
```

Thanks again...

Comment: Hey you got any solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two obvious ways to approach this. If you just want to increase the size of an individual object, you can use glScalef when drawing the object. Using scalef is easy and relatively straightforward but it isn't exactly what you're asking for.

Another solution is to apply a scaling factor to your projection matrix which will produce the desired effect. To accomplish this, just multiply the left, right, top, and bottom distances of your projection matrix by a scale like so before drawing.

gl.glFrustumf(width/2 * zoom, width/2 * zoom, height/2 * zoom, height/2 * zoom, 1, -1);

*(Note, if you're using an orthogonal matrix you will be using glOrthof instead)*

If you're interested, you can find more information about the projection matrix [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)